# Date widget/input appears to save inconsistent to display

Tags: datetime, time, gatsby, netlify, netlify-cms

I figure that this is some timezone/UTC issue - but I can't quite figure it out.

I have setup Netlify CMS on my Gatsby website using the following `config.yml`:

```
backend:
  name: git-gateway
  branch: master

publish_mode: editorial_workflow

media_folder: src/images/uploads
public_folder: /uploads

collections:
  - name: "tourInfo"
    label: "Tour Info"
    files:
      - file: "static/json/tours.json"
        label: "Tours"
        name: "tours"
        fields:
          - {label: "Tour", name: tour, widget: list, fields: [
            {label: "Date", name: date, widget: "date"},
            {label: "Spaces", name: spaces, widget: "number"},
            {label: "Booked", name: booked, widget: "number", required: false} ]}
```

I've used this to create tour dates but on doing so there's inconsistencies:

[image: Date selector]

On selecting a date through the CMS the date appears correct as above.

But then the date is saved as:

[image: Inconsistent date]

This is obviously inconsistent with the date which I input.

This behaviour is also consistent across all entered dates fetched via Gatsby on the front end:

```
[
   {
      "date":"2019-04-03T23:35:50.291Z",
      "spaces":6,
      "booked":6
   },
   {
      "date":"2019-04-17T23:36:08.718Z",
      "spaces":6,
      "booked":null
   },
   {
      "date":"2019-05-01T23:36:19.622Z",
      "spaces":6,
      "booked":null
   },
   {
      "date":"2019-05-15T23:36:33.206Z",
      "spaces":6,
      "booked":null
   },
   {
      "date":"2019-06-05T23:36:49.265Z",
      "spaces":6,
      "booked":null
   },
   {
      "date":"2019-06-19T23:37:09.924Z",
      "spaces":6,
      "booked":6
   }
]
```

They're all a day out.

I suspect this is some type of timezone issue? My locale is currently on BST.

Surely when working with the `date` widget time shouldn't matter - why does Netlify even have to save a time? I'm only inputting a date.

How can I rectify this? So when I enter 2019/04/04 I get 2019/04/04?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the ability to set the format for date in NetlifyCMS.

**Example**

```
{label: "Date", name: date, widget: "date", dateFormat: "YYYY-MM-DD", "format": "YYYY-MM-DD"},
```

- `dateFormat` is the widget output
- `format` is the data output

These formats are [`moment`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) based formatting.

[See Docs](https://www.netlifycms.org/docs/widgets/#date)

Comment: Thanks, this fixed the problem. I must admit the default behaviour still seems a little strange and error prone though.

Comment: I agree. It might be good to clear up what is going on with the date widgets in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

We can do this to disable the the date calendar only keeps the time selector:
Inside config.yml file, just need to write down something commands like this:

```
name: 'end_time'
label: 'End Time'
widget: 'datetime'
format: 'HH:mm A'
dateFormat: false
timeFormat: true
```

It will looks like this:

[image]